# chrome extension connection issues

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have written an extension for google chrome and I have a bug I need a help solving.
what I do is using either a text selection or an input of text search for photos on flickr and then create a results tab.
The extension works most of the times. but sometimes it creates a blank tab with no results and when I repeat the same search it then shows results. I figured that it's something to do with the html files messaging maybe something to do with them communicating. I have to say that I always receive the results from flickr so that the request/responce with flickr works ok. Sometimes the error happens when I play with other tabs or do something on other tabs while waiting for results. can you please help me figure out where's the fault?

the background file:

```
function searchSelection(info,tab){
var updated;
    if(info.selectionText==null){
        var value = prompt("Search Flickr", "Type in the value to search"); 
        updated=makeNewString(value);
    }
    else{
        updated=makeNewString(info.selectionText);
    }
    var resultHtml;
    var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhReq.open(
    "GET",
    "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&text="+updated+
    "&api_key=a0a60c4e0ed00af8d70800b0987cae70&content_type=7&sort=relevance&per_page=500",
    true);
    xhReq.onreadystatechange = function () {

        if (xhReq.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhReq.status == 200) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code:"document.body.style.cursor='auto';"});
                var photos = xhReq.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("photo");
                if(photos.length==0){
                    alert("No results found for this selection");
                    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code:"document.body.style.cursor='auto';"});
                    return;
                }
                var myJSPhotos=[];
                for(var i=0; i<photos.length; i++){
                    var data={"id":photos[i].getAttribute("id"),"owner":photos[i].getAttribute("owner"),
                                "secret":photos[i].getAttribute("secret"),"server":photos[i].getAttribute("server"),
                                "farm":photos[i].getAttribute("farm"),"title":photos[i].getAttribute("title")};
                    myJSPhotos[i]=data;
                }

                    chrome.tabs.create({"url":"results.html"},function(thistab){
                    var port= chrome.tabs.connect(thistab.id);
                    port.postMessage({photos:myJSPhotos});
                });

            }
        };
    };
    xhReq.send(null);
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code:"document.body.style.cursor='wait';"});

}


var context="selection";
var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "search Flickr", "contexts":[context,'page'],"onclick":searchSelection});
```

results html: has only a reference to the js file res.js

res.js :

```
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
//*****//
    var photos=msg.photos;
    createPage(photos);

  });
});
```

I have to mention that when the tab is empty if I put alert on the  `//*****//` part it won't 
fire.
but when I print out the `photos.length` at the tab create call back function part it prints out the correct result.

Comment: Please provide code for this part: `//this is the place where I send the request to flickr and edit the result into JSon`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Try to set `"run_at":"document_start"` option for your `res.js` in the manifest.</s>

I think callback from `chrome.tabs.create` is fired right away without waiting for page scripts to be loaded, so you might try something like this instead:

```
//global vars
var createdTabId = null;
var myJSPhotos = null;

xhReq.onreadystatechange = function () {

    //assign myJSPhotos to a global var

    chrome.tabs.create({"url":"results.html"},function(thistab){
        createdTabId = thistab.id;
    });
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if(changeInfo.status == "complete" && tab.id == createdTabId) {
        createdTabId = null;

        //now page is loaded and content scripts injected
        var port = chrome.tabs.connect(tab.id);
        port.postMessage({photos:myJSPhotos});

    }
});
```

Comment: but why most of the time it works fine and shows the images on the new page, and only small part of the time it shows blank page? when I do alert inside of the "create tab" it prints only when I call the context menu.

Comment: my manifest : {
  "name": "Flickr Photo Search",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon.png"},
  "background_page":"background.html",
  "permissions": ["tabs",
    "http://api.flickr.com/","contextMenus","http://*/*","https://*/*" 
  ]
}

Comment: @mary I think it is because callback on tab creation is fired without waiting for content script loading, so when you post a message through the port content script might not be there yet to receive it.

Comment: as you can see I didn't define content scripts at all but that's because I dynamically create and html file that is in my extension's folder and In this case I don't know how to create "match" in the content script.

Comment: @mary Ok I only now realized that res.js is not a content script, it is just a script included on a page. In this case `"run_at":"document_start"` isn't needed, but second part of the original answer still worth trying.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to test it. I have another question. sometimes like 1 or 2  of the images are shown as a broken image. is the fault on the result from the flickr server?